# Grab Wordpress Salt Data From URL

Tags: plugins, functions, regex

I'm looking to grab only the values of the Wordpress salt information from this URL with PHP:

https://api.wordpress.org/secret-key/1.1/salt

I want to target the second set of values within single quotation marks. Is this do-able with regex? I'm having issues

```
$url = 'https://api.wordpress.org/secret-key/1.1/salt';

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($post_data));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);

$output= curl_exec($ch);
preg_match_all("/'(.*?)'/", $output, $matches, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
var_export($matches);
```

I'm working on a tool that will automatically grab the content from the url, strip out everything except for the values of the defined keys and return it in an array. It seems to mess up alot and doesn't bring back the proper values, is there any other way to target the defined values only from the second set of quotation marks?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That returns PHP code. You can just eval it and then reference the various defines directly.

However, that is just a random number generator on the back end. There is no pattern to it. You can just generate your own random values instead of pulling them from WordPress.org and it will work just as well for whatever your purpose is.